# Jquery- create array using if statement and join array elements

Tags: php, jquery

I successfully use php implode fucnction to display drink types. Please see below code.

```
<?php 
echo 'Type:';
$types = array();    
if ($a == 1) {$types[] = 'Pepsi';}
if ($b == 1) {$types[] = 'Mirinda';}  
if ($c == 1) {$types[] = '7up';} 
echo implode(', ', $types);
?>
```

Now I need to do that with jquery i.e. create array using if statements and then join them. Could you help me to modify the code below to get the expected result.

```
$( "#view" ).html(
   '<div>+
   'Type:'+
   (a == 1?"Pepsi, " :"") +
   (b == 1?"Mirinda, " :"") +    
   (c == 1?"7up, " :"")+
   '</div>');
```

I tried in this way but it did not work:

```
 $( "#view" ).html(
       '<div>+
       'Type:'+
       (a == 1?types[] = 'Pepsi'  :types[] = '') + //syntax error
       (b == 1?types[] = 'Mirinda':types[] = '') + //syntax error   
       (c == 1?types[] = '7up'    :types[] = '')+ //syntax error
       types.join(',');
       '</div>');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest I don't know what you're trying to do there, but the join function works without all the stuff around it.

```js
var a = 1;
var b = 3;
var c = 1;

var types = [];

if (a == 1) types.push("Pepsi");
if (b == 1) types.push("Mirinda");
if (c == 1) types.push("7up"); 

$( "#view" ).html("Types: " + types.join(', '));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="view"></div>
```

Comment: I want to create array 'types'. If a == 1 then first element of array should be 'Pepsi', etc. Then I want to join all array elements.

Comment: @EducateYourself I see now, I added an example of what I think you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear to me but if you want to use `.join()` method then first you should have an array like below:

```js
var a = b = c = 1,  arr = [];

a = (a == 1) ? arr.push("Pepsi"):""; // push to array if true
b = (b == 1) ? arr.push("Coke"):""; // push to array if true
c = (c == 1) ? arr.push("7up"):""; // push to array if true

$('div').html('Types:'+ arr.join(', ')); // then join it here
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: the problem is that I do not have array ["Coke","Pepsi","7up"]. I should create it in the following way.  If a == 1 then first element of array should be 'Pepsi', etc. Then I want to join all array elements.

Comment: then declare the array and check the condition and push the values first. when you finish pusihing the values just join it in.